# App was opened from icon or notification

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification

My issue is like this.

I send a request to a server asking to notify me of an event that will occur in 2 to 10 minutes and close the app, and the server will answer to that request via a push notification. Until the server responds with the notification, the app shows an animation, just in case it stays in the foreground.

When i receive the notification, when the app is opened, the animation has to stop and display some data from the notification. 
My problem is, if i don't open the app from the notification (i open it from the icon), the animation continues to show because the callback method for "didReceiveRemoteNotification" never gets called..

Is it possible to check if an app was opened from the icon or from a notification (local or push)?

Comment: But if you want the loading icon to show till there is a response then this is desired?  It seems to me that the animation should say, "waiting for response from server".  The only other thing is that you can find out which delegate method gets called when the notification is pressed and use the other entry points for clearing the animation (not opened via notification link)

Comment: I did use a different entry point and got it to work, as MrTj and you have suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidFinishLaunchingWithOptions%3a) paragraph of the SDK help explains very well which delegate methods are called in different start / wake up scenarios (for example clicking registered URL handler, opening a supported mime type, answering to remote / local notifications, clicking on the icon on the home screen, etc)

Also, if your application is already running at the time of the above events, the appropriate delegate methods will be called (for example `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, `openURL`, etc.) apart from `applicationDidBecomeActive:`. From the combination of the called callbacks you can figure out which event happened.

Comment: Using "didfinishlaunch.." was not an option since the app was running  when opened. But i did the second part and i got it to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by checking the launchOptions object. That should tell whether you opened your app directly or as a result of notification.

You can do some thing like this:

```
if(!launchOptions){
    NSLog(@"App invoked directly");
}
```

Comment: This would be a good solution if the app was not already running. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to your AppDelegate's applicationWillEnterForeground method:

-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

```
// this method is called when staring an app that was closed / killed / never run before (after applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions) and every time the app is reopened or change status from background to foreground (ex. returning from a mobile call or after the user switched to other app and then came back)

[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<UNNotification *> * _Nonnull notifications) {
    NSLog(@"AppDelegate-getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler there were %lu notifications in notification center", (unsigned long)[notifications count]); 

    for (UNNotification* notification in notifications) {

        NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
        if (userInfo) {
            NSLog(@"Processed a notification in getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler, with this info: %@", userInfo);
            [self showPushNotificationInAlertController:userInfo]; // this is my method to display the notification in an UIAlertController
        }
    }
    UIApplication.sharedApplication.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

}];
```

} 
}

Remove this line from the method application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: if you had included it there, because it clears the badge number and also all notifications in notifications center:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

This is currently working in iOS 12, hadn't have the chance to test it in earlier versions.
You also have to implement code in this method to process notifications received while the app is in the foreground:   willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:
and this method to process notifications in which the user opens your app by tapping the notification:  didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler: